# How to calculate the % change between 2 tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function that performs calculations on dictionary keys, and updates them. Each key is a 4-D point (a tuple), for example:

```
original_key = (6.0, 3.0, 4.8, 1.8)
updated_key = (6.513333333333332, 2.962666666666666, 5.238666666666668, 1.833333333333333)
```

I'd like that the function will stop updates the keys, once the % change between the original key and the new key will be 10% or less.

How can I calculate the change between 2 tuples with this structure? (note: it is ok to change it to other types other then tuple)

***Edit***
Consider a 4-d space, and I'd like to check if the change between the distance of 2 points changed in 10% or less

Comment: How do you define the percent change? Do you mean the percent change between each "coordinate" in the 4-D point?

Comment: I meant in total, not each coordinate

Comment: What do you mean by total? The change in euclidean distance?

Comment: How would you make sense of a total percent change? the whole 10% change could come from any of the members of the tuple

Comment: You can use something like `for item in zip(original_key, updated_key):` which will give you a tuple (orig, updated) and compare the way you like.

Comment: Yes, in euclidian distance. Consider a 4-d space, and I'd like to check if the change between the distance of 2 points changed in 10% or less

Comment: so just use output of zip and calculate euclidian distance with lambda or helper function.

Comment: Can you write a sample code to what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't already have a distance function, define one e.g.

```
from math import sqrt

def distance(a, b):
    return sqrt(sum([(p - q)**2 for p,q in zip(a, b)]))
```

or use a lambda as mentioned in the comments, and stop updating when `abs(distance(current_key, new_key) / distance(current_key, old_key)) <= 0.1`.